# Using code defined in separate file in Go

Tags: go

Say I have got code for a project spread across multiple files. Is there any other way to reference such code within files in the project without going through the whole build and install process? For example within a single project, I might have an implementation of a type Foo in file A and I might want to use such type in file B within the same project. Is there anyway to go about doing that

Comment: can you add some code to explain your situation more clearly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear to me what exactly you're asking about, but this part of the language specs about ["Declarations and scope"](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope) might be related and/or helpful. Another, more prosaic source of related information might probably be ["How to Write Go Code"](http://golang.org/doc/code.html).

EDIT - Expanding on now expanded question:

If "package a" declares type `Foo` - then, b/c `Foo` starts with an upper case letter - `Foo` is *exported* by `a`. Then in "package b" one would write `import "a"` and can then refer to that type as `a.Foo` inside "package b".

Comment: Thats not exactly my problem. I am referring to a situation where you have two files within the same project or package and one is using say a type declared within the other

Comment: That's the package scope case from the first link above, i.e. any top level declaration is visible through the whole package == all of the package files.

Comment: just to put it another way, if file `a` and file `b` are in the same directory with the same package name, and type `Foo` is in file `a`, then you implicitly have access to `Foo` in file `b`. Nothing else is needed.